# Store keystroke bash

Tags: bash

I'm very new to bash-programming, say I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i sum=0
declare -i count=0

while [ $count -lt 5 ]; do
read addition
let sum=sum+addition
let count++
done
echo "$sum"
```

Which basically sums together the read input 5 times. Instead I want it to do such until I use a specific keystroke, like ctrl+d. Below is the code (obviously missing the code I need to register a keystroke, and then break the loop) i wish:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i sum=0

while true; do
read addition
let sum=sum+addition
if [ ]; then #what should I insert, do I need additional lines to register keystrokes?
break;
fi
done
echo "$sum"
```

Please feel free to correct me if something seems wrong as well - this is my very first post on stackoverflow, actually.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would write what you're trying to do like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0
count=0
while read -r addition && (( ++count < 5 )); do
   (( sum += addition ))
done
echo "$sum"
```

This will terminate after 5 reads or when the exit code of `read` is non-zero (a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> will do that).

A couple of points on what you did:

- There's no need to use `declare -i`, especially when you're initialising the variable when you declare it (but I guess there's also no harm in it)
- `let` is old bash syntax, you can (and should) use the more up to date `(( ))`. Alternatively, you could use the more widely compatible (POSIX compliant) `sum=$((sum+1))`.

Comment: Ok, thank you - I will take notice on the declare -i and (( )) syntax :)

Comment: No problem. By the way, unless you require any further clarification, you should accept your favourite answer (not necessarily this one!) so your question is marked as solved.

Comment: Using `declare -i sum` lets you write `sum+=addition` without wrapping it in an arithmetic command. Not better or worse, just different.

Comment: `((...))` is more general, though, so I've never really seen the point in using `declare -i` :)

Comment: @Superdids NB [chepner's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760205/store-keystroke-bash/25760606#comment40291174_25760602) beneath the accepted answer. Personally I would say that using Ctrl-d to break the loop (as in my answer) is in fact a good idea, as it serves the purpose it was intended for.

Comment: As this was my first post, I thought I could "accept" multiple suggestions, so it is now fixed :)

Comment: @Superdids when you get 15 reputation points, you can upvote all of the answers you find useful but you can only accept one answer to your question. It's all mentioned in [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you can find out more details in the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you're looking for a way to break out of the loop once you've entered all the numbers you want to sum, you could use the `trap` command.

If you're new to bash programming, it's a command that will trap signals (like Ctrl+c) and cause another routine to be executed.  In this case, you would probably execute a `break`-type command.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use `ctrl+d` which means essentially `EOF` or 'no more input' which will cause your shell to disconnect. As you have found, most signals are used with `kill` and require the use of the `trap` function which is not what you are wanting here. (you can use trap, but it will end your script). Why not take advantage of the fact that variables are not `typed` in bash and simply choose some value or word to break out of the loop with? Your first script could be edited to provide:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i sum=0

while read addition; do
    [ "$addition" = "done" ] && break
    let sum=sum+addition
done
echo "$sum"
```

When executing the script manually, when you are done, simply type "done" or whatever you choose. Example:

```
$ ./script.sh
10
10
10
15
done
45
```

The script will automatically exit and provide the `sum` if you provide a file with numbers to it by `cat` to stdin. E.g. (file with same numbers on separate lines):

```
$ cat somefile.txt | ./script.sh
45
```

Comment: ctrl+d was basically a suggestion, just finding a proper key as an example isnt that easy being inexperienced in bash-programming! And yes, I would, myself, simply use a value to break the loop - I was just curious, actually.

Comment: You're in good company. I've done this for decades and trapping a key to complete input in bash always requires a creative fix. Any of the signals you could generate, e.g. SIGHUP, SIGINT, etc.. would require trapping and managing with `kill`. Instead of "done" make it a capital `C` - at least you get the feel of trapping a signal :)

Comment: Nice, thanks! I got some reading and coding to do now, it seems ^^

Comment: Control-D only causes the shell to exit if you type it at the shell prompt, since you are ending the file the *shell* uses for standard input. Typing it when the `read` command is waiting for input will simply cause `read` to exit with nonzero status.